# Knockout binding text in button with icon

Tags: html, data-binding, knockout.js

In my HTML page I need to include a button element with a description and an icon (I use an icon from the fontawesome.com library).

To compile the data in my page I use the Knockout Javascript framework.

Compilation of the descriptive text of the button is done by text binding as in the example:

```html
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" data-bind="text:GetTranslatedText('SomeText')">
  <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
</button>
```

The GetTranslatedText("SomeText") function returns the text translated into the language used by the user.

My problem is that when the framework compiles the text of the button, it overwrites the `<i>` element with which the icon is displayed.

Is there a simple way to concatenate both the text and HTML element of the icon into the binding?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than binding the text to the button, which as you've seen overrides the buttons contents, bind it to a span alongside the icon:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
  <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> <span data-bind="text:GetTranslatedText('SomeText')"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Great work-around, it works!